# Alignment after equal sign

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How can I align a split equation starting with a negative term such that the minus sign in the second line (which is indeed a binary operator) is exactly below the negative sign as automatically generated by the `dmath` environment from the `breqn` package? Perhaps my manual alignment looks better after all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

    \[
    \begin{split}
    a={}&  {-b}+c\\
    & -d+e
    \end{split}
    \]

    \begin{dmath*}
        a = -b+c\\-d+e
    \end{dmath*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but I think the `multlined` environment (from `mathtools`) looks nicer, at least in the case at hand.

Comment: I actually have a very long term on the right side. Because of that I would like to have an alignment.

Comment: Unless you know the precise typography rules for unary vs binary minus, you might as well just fudge a \hspace{-2.3pt}.

Comment: If I understand your intent correctly, what you want is `... & \mspace{-\medmuskip}-d+e ...`.  @JohnKormylo: see the table on p. 170 of _The TeXbook_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image: Output of the code that follows]

Since a `\medmuskip` (normally `4.0mu plus 2.0mu minus 4.0mu`) is inserted both before and after a binary operator (see the table on p. 170 of *The TeXbook*), and since you want to remove the space before the `-` sign, while retaining the one after it, the easiest thing of all is to compensate for the former by adding a negative space of the same magnitude:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

    \[
    \begin{split}
    a={}&  {-b}+c\\
    & \mspace{-\medmuskip}-d+e
    \end{split}
    \]

    \begin{dmath*}
        a = -b+c\\-d+e
    \end{dmath*}

\end{document}
```

Please note that this is only appropriate for equations typeset in `\displaystyle` and in `\textstyle`.  For the same trick to work in script styles too, the correct incantation would be `\nonscript\mspace{-\medmuskip}` (but who could ever need this in script styles?).